# Why is $\emptyset$ the only open null set?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, borel-measures

I read multiple times that for a topological space $(\Omega,O)$ with countable basis $F$ and Borel-measure $\mu$, "obviously", the only open null set is the empty set. I don't find that so obvious. Can anyone explain that to me?

Comment: Can you give a citation for this claim? It might be helpful (e.g. there might be additional implicit assumptions involved).

Comment: Where did you read that? It's obviously false - so obviously false that I doubt that you actually read it, you must be leaving something out. (For example, define a Borel measure $|mu$ on $\Bbb R$ by $\mu(E)=m(E\cap[0,1])$.)

Comment: Thank you for the useful comments. As you supposed, it was my mistake and the measure was defined pretty much how David C. Ullrich stated it. It was in a german measure theory script from two years ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without further restrictions, it's not true in general. For a silly example, consider the set $X=\{a, b\}$ with the discrete topology, and the Borel measure $\mu$ on $X$ given by $$\mu(\emptyset)=\mu(\{a\})=0,\quad \mu(\{b\})=\mu(X)=1.$$

Comment: Right, except it's  not silly. The silly example is $\mu=0$.